# kubeconfig authorization expire, how to extend？

Tags: kubernetes, google, google-kubernetes-engine

By billing account, i create a gke cluster where connecting cluster by kubectl in cloud shell vm. 
however, i download kubeconfig to my local, connection is ok at the beginning after that connection does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your gcloud auth-provider has been logged off.

1) Log in back to gcloud

```
gcloud auth login
```

It will open a browser and you will be prompt to put your gcloud username and password

2) Update kubectl config with the project context

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <your-cluster-name> --zone <project-zone> --project <your-project-name>
```